# Use std::move in C++11 move constructor with uniform initialization syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-constructor

I have this simple class:

```
struct Worker
{
        Worker() : done{false} {}
        Worker(const Worker& rhs) : done{rhs.done}, qworker{} {}
        Worker(Worker &&rhs) : done{rhs.done}
        {
            qworker = std::move(rhs.qworker);
        }
...
}
```

this compile fine with gcc-4.7.2 but if I try to use this version I obtain an error

```
struct Worker
{
        Worker() : done{false} {}
        Worker(const Worker& rhs) : done{rhs.done}, qworker{} {}
        Worker(Worker &&rhs) : done{rhs.done}
                             , qworker{std::move(rhs.qworker)} // <- ERROR
        {
        }
...
}
```

Why?

```
In file included from tlog.cpp:8:0:
log11.hpp: In member function ‘void Log11::Worker::run()’:
log11.hpp:34:29: error: ‘class std::vector<std::function<void()> >’ has no member named ‘pop_front’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:39:0,
                 from tlog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional: In instantiation of ‘static void std::_Function_handler<void(_ArgTypes ...), _Functor>::_M_invoke(const std::_Any_data&, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = std::vector<std::function<void()> >; _ArgTypes = {}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:2298:6:   required from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::vector<std::function<void()> >; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}; typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void()>::_Useless]’
log11.hpp:20:78:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/functional:1926:2: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::function<void()> >) ()’
```

Comment: What is the type of `qworker`?

Comment: std::deque<std::function<void()>> qworker;

Comment: Hm, that may be a bug. It compiles on GCC 4.8.0 (see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3705))

Comment: Thanks Andy just test on 4.8 and I can confirm: now compile! :( it's a bug?

Comment: @Gian Change the braces to parentheses and it will compile on gcc 4.7.2. `qworker(std::move(rhs.qworker))`

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of anything else than a bug, yes. But finding out what exactly is going on is likely beyond my capabilities at the moment

Comment: It's not a bug, it's http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2132 which I implemented in GCC 4.8

Comment: @JonathanWakely: But wait a second: isn't the constructor accepting an `initializer_list` supposed to be invoked, when braces are used?

Comment: @AndyProwl, if `{x}` can be converted to `initializer_list<value_type>` yes, otherwise no.  The problem is that `std::function` has a constructor template that allows construction from _any_ type, so `{x}` can be converted to `initializer_list<value_type>` (even though that makes no sense because `x` is not callable). LWG 2132 contrains the problematic constructor, so the move constructor gets called as intended.

Comment: @AndyProwl I don't understand your question, can you explain again? Thanks!

Comment: @GianLorenzoMeocci: Jonathan explained everything in his answer (including why using parentheses instead of braces works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++11 standard `std::function` has an unconstrained constructor template that accepts any argument type:

```
template<class F> function(F f);
```

When you say `qworker{std::move(rhs.qworker)}` this first attempts to call a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<std::function<void()>>`.  Because of the unconstrained constructor template shown above, a `std::function<void()>` can be constructed from *any* type, so you get an `initializer_list` with one member, like this:

```
{ std::function<void()>{std::move(rhs.qworker)} }
```

This is invalid, because `rhs.qworker` is not a callable object, but the error only happens when you try to invoke the function objects.

If you say `qworker(std::move(rhs.qworker))` then the initializer list constructor is not a candidate and the move constructor is called instead.

There is a defect report against the standard ([LWG 2132](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2132)) which fixes this by preventing the `function(F)` constructor template being called unless the argument is a callable object.  That prevents an `initializer_list<function<void()>>` being created, and instead `qworker{std::move(rhs.qworker)}` calls the move constructor, as intended.  GCC 4.7 does not implement the resolution for LWG 2132, but GCC 4.8 does.