# G++, clang++ and std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I was just playing around with the new std::function from C++11, and I wrote an example that compiles with clang++ 3.2 and the Intel C++ compiler 13.1 but not with g++ 4.8. Before I report this as a bug, I thought I'd check that I'm not doing something really stupid and that this should actually compile.
So, is the following code valid c++11?

```
template <typename C>
void map(C& c, std::function<typename C::value_type(typename C::value_type)> f)
{
    for(auto& x : c) {
        x = f(x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    map(v, [](int x) { return x+2; });

    for(auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I realise that this code isn't very useful but it struck me as odd that clang and Intel C++ compiled it and gcc didn't.

EDIT: gcc will also not compile the same code when passing map a functor or function pointer:

```
struct {
    int operator() (int a) {
        return a+2;
    }
} add2s;
map(v, add2s);

int add2 (int a) {
    return a+2;
}
map(v,add2);
```

clang and icpc also compile both of these.

Comment: What's the error, g++ shows you?

Comment: clang 3.0 with -std=c++11 crash dumps on this code

Comment: `'main()::<lambda(int)>' is not derived from 'std::function<typename C::value_type(typename C::value_type)>'` I guess, that's at least what I get.

Comment: @nurettin: Clang 3.0 is *old*.

Comment: I would have expected such an error message for a reference or pointer parameter, but for a value it seems odd.

Comment: Just to note this (although you most certainly have tried this already) after manually converting the lambda to a `std::function` object the code works.

Comment: I get: `test.cpp:41:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(std::vector<int>&, main()::__lambda0)’`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998402/c11-does-not-deduce-type-when-stdfunction-or-lambda-functions-are-involved

Comment: I wonder if it couldn't be related to the change @JonathanWakely is talking about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15865276/1932150). Notice, that [you can fix this by adding braces aroung the lambda](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy$3809)

Comment: @filmor: There's no type deduction going on here, `C` is deduced from the first argument

Comment: Why not?
`template<typename C, typename F> void map(C& c, F f)`

Comment: @balki: C should be deduced from the first argument, then replaced in the type of the second parameter. The second argument in itself does not participate to type deduction

Comment: @balki: (I'm referring to the OP's example in my previous comment, not yours. In your example of course there is type deduction going on for both parameter types)

Comment: @AndyProwl Ok. However, this seems to work in all compilers http://liveworkspace.org/code/6UvzJ$0

Comment: @balki: I don't doubt it: I believe the OP has hit a bug, and the bug is somehow related to copy-initialization of an `std::function` object. Your example does not use `std::function`.

Comment: @AndyProwl, it is related to that change I made to `std::function`, but only in as much as the change causes it to hit a G++ bug. The `std::function` change itself is OK and should compile, but doesn't, as shown by the reduced example in my answer below.

Comment: @AndyProwl, you're right there _shouldn't_ be any type deduction, because `function<typename C::value_type(typename C::value_type)>` is a non-deduced context, but for some reason that fails, but it works with `std::function<int(int)>` which should be equivalent. See the bugzilla report for more details.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Thank you for clarifying once again. Your answer makes it clear that the change itself only helped revealing an existing bug, rather than being the culprit. (+1ed already)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a G++ bug, it can be reduced to the following example which doesn't use `std::function` (or anything from the standard library):

```
template<typename T>
struct function
{
    function(int)
    { }
};

struct V {
  typedef int value_type;
};

template <typename C>
void map(C&, function<typename C::value_type>)
{
}

int main()
{
  V v;
  map(v, 1);
}
```

I've reported it to bugzilla as [PR 56874](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56874).  The problem is not related to lambdas, but to a type in a non-deduced context incorrectly causing argument deduction to fail.

Comment: maybe add the part about non-deduced context from your comment to your answer, too.

Comment: Incidentally, you reported this as being specific to lambdas, but it will not compile when passing functors or function pointers either. Is that a different bug or part of the same one?

Comment: @dtruby, I've updated the answer above and the bugzilla report: it won't compile when passing an `int` either